# Access router admin page with static IP

Tags: web, static-ip, wide-area-network

I have a static IP and can access my servers from the outside world by port mapping.
For e.g.: A service running on the `192.168.1.98:8080`, can be accessed by going to `{Static_IP}:8080`, if I have mapped 8080 of the `192.168.1.98` to `8080` external port.

The IP of my router is 192.168.1.1, now, when I want to access the router admin page, I map `192.168.1.1:80` to port 80 on the static IP(external port), but I cannot access the router admin page from the outside world. How can I do this?

My router is Huawei HG630a.

PS: I have to use such an old DSL router as I need static IP and the ISP that provides static IP doesn't have fiber poles laid here. Other ISPs that have fiber don't provide static IP.

Comment: Your router can't do port forwarding from its own public IP on the WAN interface to its own private IP on the LAN interface. Instead, you need to enable "remote management" in the router settings. (Writing a comment instead of an answer because I don't know how to change this setting on your particular model.)

Comment: Why can the router not do that forwarding? I'm curious to know.
Thanks for the comment, I will check the remote management thing.
Also, after enabling the remote management, do I have to do anything else?
@MosheKatz

Comment: If you open remote management, you need to make sure your passphrase is good enough. Enabling TLS would also be ideal. Otherwise it is a good target for abuse.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your server is set up correctly and static IP addresses configured properly on the clients, and troubleshooting only RG settings, first check the router's configuration and firewall rules.

Make sure router has enabled remote management which is enabling access to the router from a WAN (usually under access tab).
The same applies to some routers which are blocking ICMP packets and if you trying to ping from remote server from WAN the request is or time out or ping is completely denied as inside RG settings under firewall is not enabled. Are you able to ping RG?

With a static IP you have to go to every device on the LAN to set the address of that device, and you need to make sure that none of the addresses are the same otherwise there can arise IP address conflict.

Then you can connect and configure the router through telnet from remote location
Here you can find Telnet set up for your Huawai Gateway https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100130782/57c0c6c1/example-for-logging-in-to-the-router-using-telnet

When accesing the Router interface from LAN is the static IP matching with the one showing up on the CMD ipconfig result (gateway IP) of the device which you run CMD prompt on (if windows)?
Isn't there any DHCP configuration?

Disable web proxies, factory reset router, update firmawe, clear ARP and then run ping from different client on WAN and share the tracert to see if only from your server unable to access or from another clients on WAN the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your router defined the subnet it created as 192.168.1.x/24 as it assigned its own IP as 192.168.1.1. No matter what IP it assigned to other terminals in this subnet, from 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254, they are only Private IP's.

That means if your mother call you the "big brother", it is within your family and a mail cannot find who or where the "big brother" is, and there are many other "big brother"s in different families. (Yes every router by default would create its net as 192.168.1.x/24 while sitting at 192.168.1.1)

Most ISP's won't provide a Public IP because it costs money. If you want to access your server from anywhere in the world, you need to rent a public IP for the World Wide Web to identify it. Usually you can get one for free once you rent a VPS on a cloud.

---

Reply to the comment " I already have a public static IP. My question is accessing the router admin page from the outside world." - You have to configure the firewall on that public static IP. And it is beyond the knowledge on Linux. You should inquire the one who provides you the public static IP.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the point, I already have a public static IP. My question is accessing the router admin page from the outside world.